# Customize AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android

Can I customize AlertDialog **without using custom dialog**? As I want to show my **cancel button** after yes or no button on the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
make custom layout in xml. then set your custom xml to your alert dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
Button yes = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.yes);
yes.onClickListenere(......./do what you want);
```

Comment: Can I customize AlertDialog **without using custom dialog?**

Comment: All I forgot was that builder has 'setView' and not 'setContentView'.

Answer (score 0):

Thre is no way to alter the order of buttons. But you could do this and implement required button click events accordingly.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```